# SideMenu: How to include in Objective-C project?

Tags: objective-c, swift, side-menu

I'm trying to use the project SideMenu (https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu) inside my Objective-C code (I saw the @objc/@objcMembers syntax so I'm guessing it should be possible) and I'm not using storyboards.
Can the controller be used in this scenario? If so, how?
It seems I correctly imported the module as I'm able to see the classes with autocompletion, but if I try to instantiate a SideMenuNavigationController, I cannot access the initWithRootViewController method.
Is there anybody who could point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: In swift it will be: `SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: YourViewController)` or `SideMenuNavigationController.init(rootViewController: YourViewController)`

Comment: Yes, that's what I found on the documentation. In Obj-C I would do `[[SideMenuNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:YourViewController]`, but it doesn't recognize the method, even if there's the @objcMembers declaration in the Swift code.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already figured this out, but in Objective-C, the class is exposed as `UISideMenuNavigationController` instead. So, you end up with:

```
UISideMenuNavigationController *menu = [[UISideMenuNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thank you for your suggestion.
Unfortunately, I get an error when trying your solution:

`'initWithRootViewController:' is unavailable
Unknown receiver 'UISideMenuNavigationController'; did you mean 'SideMenuNavigationController'?
Replace 'UISideMenuNavigationController' with 'SideMenuNavigationController'`

Replacing UISideMenuNavigationController with SideMenuNavigationController leads to the error:
`'initWithRootViewController:' is unavailable`

Comment: @zionun : have you find the solution.i am facing same issue.

Comment: @DaxeshNagar Yes, I used a fork of the project. You can put it in your Podfile like this:
`pod 'SideMenu', :git => 'https://github.com/DanielFontes/SideMenu.git', :commit => '52361cfee8cd89698cc131729d9f337d8fafcffe';`
Then, you can instantiate it as you normally would with an Objective-C class.

Comment: @DaxeshNagar Here is an example of how I used it in my project:
`SideMenuSettings *_settings = [[SideMenuSettings alloc] init];
[_settings setPresentationStyle:SideMenuPresentationStyle.menuSlideIn];
SideMenuPresentationStyle *_style = _settings.presentationStyle;
_style.presentingScaleFactor = 0.9;
SideMenuNavigationController *_sideMenu = [[SideMenuNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sectionsView settings:_settings];
[_sideMenu setLeftSide:YES];            
[[SideMenuManager defaultManager] setLeftMenuNavigationController:_sideMenu];`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I adopted, in case someone was running into the same problem.
In your pod file, use this fork of the SideMenu project:

```
pod 'SideMenu', :git => 'https://github.com/DanielFontes/SideMenu.git', :commit => '52361cfee8cd89698cc131729d9f337d8fafcffe';
```

Then, you can instantiate SideMenu as you normally would with an Objective-C class; here is how I configured it in my project:

```
YourViewController *_view = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NibName" bundle:nil];

SideMenuSettings *_settings = [[SideMenuSettings alloc] init];
[_settings setPresentationStyle:SideMenuPresentationStyle.menuSlideIn];
SideMenuPresentationStyle *_selectedPresentationStyle = _settings.presentationStyle;
_selectedPresentationStyle.presentingScaleFactor = 0.9;

float width = (self.isiPad)?570:300;
[_settings setMenuWidth:width];
            
SideMenuNavigationController *_sideMenu = [[SideMenuNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_view settings:_settings];
[_sideMenu setSideMenuDelegate:self];
[_sideMenu setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[_sideMenu setLeftSide:YES];
[_sideMenu setStatusBarEndAlpha:0];
            
[[SideMenuManager defaultManager] setLeftMenuNavigationController:_sideMenu];
[[SideMenuManager defaultManager] addPanGestureToPresentToView:_firstViewController.navigationController.navigationBar];
[[SideMenuManager defaultManager] addScreenEdgePanGesturesToPresentToView:_firstViewController.view];
```